# Exception when creating a JSML Window in Java

Tags: java

```
import org.jsfml.window.*;
import org.jsfml.graphics.*;
import org.jsfml.internal.*;
import org.jsfml.window.event.Event;

public class Jsmql {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ContextActivationException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        VideoMode vm = new VideoMode(100, 100);
        Window fen = new Window(vm, "aaa");
        while(fen.isOpen()) {
            fen.display();
            Event event = fen.pollEvent();
            if (event.type == Event.Type.CLOSED) {
                fen.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want to create Java window with JSML in Java ( http://pdinklag.de/jsfml/ )
I have the exception below when laucnhing my code:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   jsmql.Jsmql.main(Jsmql.java:29)
>   /Users/me/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I looked the signification of Java NullPointerException but I don't succeded to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running this code? The error message says line 29, but your snippet has only 24 lines.

Comment: Yes, the error is on the line `if (event.type == Event.Type.CLOSED)`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at documentation of the  [Window.pollEvent() method](https://github.com/pdinklag/JSFML/blob/master/src/java/org/jsfml/window/Window.java#L355) you could see that it says:

> return the event currently on top of the event stack, or null if there is none

So you should check that `event` isn't null, before accessing its `type` property:

```
if (event != null && event.type == Event.Type.CLOSED) {
    fen.close();
}
```